# How to signal and control a salvaged speaker amplifier circuit to turn on

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, schematics

I am trying to convert a dvd/theatre system into a stand-alone speaker amplifier. I have removed the dvd/radio parts and I have the power amplifier parts. The parts I removed with the on button uses a 3 pin controller cable to connect to the amplifier parts. I am trying to create that SP-On signal to turn it on. I don't know how to create that signal. I circled in red the diagram below where the 3 pin control is. Can anyone advise me on how to do this? I have all the parts in the below diagram intact and it is receiving power from my AC 230V plug. I just don't know how to give it the signal to turn on. Heres also a link to the servicing manual https://diagramas.diagramasde.com/otros/Sanyo%20DC-PT100.pdf

[image]

Comment: Switch it to GND. What else?

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean by switch it to GND? Please explain as I'm less than a novice at best.

Comment: That is a switch between SP-ON & GND. Meantime, some power amps have automatic speaker on delay, not to blow up the speaker and/or the driver. That case you may just short out SP-ON & GND.

Comment: I shorted SP-On & GND by connecting them together with a female-female breadboard jumper however the power LED is still not turning on, and still not getting any sound.

Comment: wait a second.. sorry that I did not read the schematics, but just looked at the pinout..

Comment: Okay, SO, my guess was wrong, sorry. SP-ON is not the speaker-on of audio power amp. It actually is the power button, but it is active, not passive.  It looks like, one of the sub unit you removed works as a console/central-control-panel, and it supplied voltage to the SP-ON (grounded on GND). To turn on the power, supply +12V to SP-ON through a diode (!! important). Once it turns on, it wouldn't shut off, keep talking, :-), until unplugged. The console had some sort of power control including cut off relay. Good luck.